# Post axios request in Vue2 callback isn't working correctly

Tags: javascript, http, post, vuejs2, axios

In my Vue2 application I am preforming a POST request with axios:

```
window.axios.post(`/clients/${this.getClientId}/connection`, {
                    clientType: newClientType,
                    url: this.client.url,
                    username: this.client.username,
                    password: this.client.password
                }).then((success)=>{

                console.log(success);

                },(error)=>{

                console.log(error);

                })
```

If this gets a 400 or 409(Any error responses) response the console.log I get is just 'false', whereas I would normally get a proper response, Don't understand why this response is different?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,it is a syntax from the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#example)

```
window.axios.post(`/clients/${this.getClientId}/connection`, {
                    clientType: newClientType,
                    url: this.client.url,
                    username: this.client.username,
                    password: this.client.password
                }).then((success)=>{

                console.log(success);

                }.catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                 });
```

Comment: Tried this still now change in the response

Comment: can you post your request/response ?